# Debug Error: String Resource 7176 was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I have upgraded my project to VS2010 from VC++.NET 2003. I am getting Debug Error: String Resource 7176 was not found. I could see string table contains string for String Resource 7176 but still error is displaying when I call Custom_MessageBox() which works well in other modules in same project.

In TestResource.rh

```
#define IDS_SHOWWARNING_TEST        7176
```

In TestResource.rc

```
#include "DevControl.rh"

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
IDS_SHOWWARNING_TEST           "Test1"
END
```

In TestResource.cpp

```
 BOOL TestFunc(hParentWnd)
{
     LPCTSTR myString = "Hello"
     Custom_MessageBox( hParentWnd,
                  MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDS_SHOWWARNING_TEST),
                  MB_OK | MCC_INFORMATION );
 }
```

If I pass myString in place of MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDS_TEST ) then it works perfectly.

Please find the definition of Custom_MessageBox(). If I see value of pszText, it shows bad pointer. MAKEINTRESOURCE is not able to evaluate IDS_SHOWWARNING_TEST. I don't know the reason.

```
const int CUS_RETURN_ERROR        = (int)0xFFFF;

int cdecl Custom_MessageBox( HWND hwndOwner, LPCTSTR pszText, UINT uStyle, ... )
{
   // handle variable parms
   va_list sVarArgs;
   va_start(sVarArgs, uStyle);

   if (!pszText)
      return CUS_RETURN_ERROR;

   CMDMsgDialog Dlg;
   int nReturn = Dlg.MessageDialog(hwndOwner, pszText, uStyle, sVarArgs);

   va_end(sVarArgs);
   return nReturn;
}
```

Comment: What is Custom_MessageBox doing? Can it handle string resources? Does your code call AfxSetResourceHandle? Can the string be loaded at the beginning of InitInstance?

Comment: What happens if you call `MessageBox` instead of ` Custom_MessageBox`?

Comment: You need to show the source code for `Custom_MessageBox` as that's the function that fails.

Comment: I have replaced "hParentWnd" with "AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd()" and it is working fine now. Not sure Why?

Comment: @S.Shil show how you called `TestFunc`.

Comment: If you want us to find out why it didn't work before, then  you must show us the `Custom_MessageBox` function.

Comment: @Michael Walz please find the definition of Custom_MessageBox above.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined IDS_SHOWWARNING_TEST in your TestResource.rh:

```
#define IDS_SHOWWARNING_TEST        7176
```

However, in your TestResource.rc you include different header file:

```
#include "DevControl.rh"
```

The macro IDS_SHOWWARNING_TEST is probably also defined in that file, with a different value.

Comment: I have modified this code to put on social website as I don't want to show actual code so I missed to replace "DevControl.rh" to TestResource.rh. This is just an example.

Comment: I can only see the code you posted, NOT what you have on your computer :) Anyway, the error clearly indicates that you DO pass the string ID correctly (as you expect it to be 7176, and that's what is in the error message). This means that the string with that ID is **NOT** in the resources that are searched. Do you have multiple resource modules (in exe and in dll)? Do you have multiple languages resources?